# While loop runs with an undefined function's name as a condition

Tags: c, gcc

Why does this code run?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int i();
int main(){
    while(i){printf("Hi");}
}
```

What exactly is the value of i that the while loop accepts?

I tried `printf("%d", i)` and it said that `i` is undefined which was expected since it has only declaration, but why does `while` work?

Comment: `i` on its own evaluates to the address of the function, ie, a *true* value. Since you never call the function or use the value for anything other than *true* or *false*, compiler can optimize and ignore the fact that the function is not defined.

Comment: another issue is that `printf("%d", i)` invokes UB, because you can only print `int`s with `%d`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you compile with proper warnings enabled, you'll see

```
warning: the address of ‘i’ will always evaluate as ‘true’ [-Waddress]
     while(i){printf("Hi\n");}
```

Here, the value of `i` is taken as the address of the function, i.e., the function pointer.

To add a bit more context, from [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wno-address) (*emphasis mine*)

> `-Waddress`
>
> Warn about suspicious uses of memory addresses. These include **using the address of a function in a conditional expression, such as `void func(void); if (func)`,** and comparisons against the memory address of a string literal, such as `if (x == "abc")`. **Such uses typically indicate a programmer error: the address of a function always evaluates to true, so their use in a conditional usually indicate that the programmer forgot the parentheses in a function call;** and comparisons against string literals result in unspecified behavior and are not portable in C, so they usually indicate that the programmer intended to use `strcmp`. This warning is enabled by `-Wall`.

Comment: Does that mean a function address is regarded to be non-NULL even if the function is not defined at all? I would expect to get the same linker error regarding undefined identifier as the author gets with printing `i`.

Comment: I think this is implementation defined or it is beyond the C standard. Ex. with `gcc` and  `__attribute__((__weak__)) int i()` the address will evaluate to NULL in case no function declaration is found during link.

Answer (score 0):

You have the function declaration `int i();`

The C11 standard (n1570) states in [6.3.2.1/4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p4):

> A function designator is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, **a function designator with type ‘‘function returning type’’ is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘pointer to function returning type’’.**

So `i` in `while(i)` is the pointer to function, and since it is an address, it will always evaluate to true.

Comment: It talks about function parameters, does it not?